# Decompiling Linq queries from .net assembly

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, .net-4.0

I have to decompile an assembly that contains some linq-to-sql code (about 30 methods). I have tried many decompilers like dotpeek, Telerik's just decompile, RedGate's .NET reflactor (evaluation) but all of them decompile linq queries in form of dynamic linq. Is there a free reflector that can extract original Linq queries from .NET assembly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "dynamic linq". Are you talking method chaining vs linq syntax (i.e. .Where().Select() vs from a where b select c)?

Comment: C# iterators and lambda expressions are the built-in obfuscator in .NET.  Decompilers don't tackle them, it's too hard.

Comment: This feature is on Telerik's JustDecompile Roadmap for Q3 2013. So check it in couple of month. http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler/roadmap.aspx